# when I retrieve data from database in php and display it that time how to hide password field in display table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I need hide password in displaying table
so how to hide this data in PHP, JavaScript

Here Is My Co: de  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fboD5egyDld7T9qvMcRZoj7YAKtoPeVp3pYs2u8Q1Nw/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Are you really keeping the password in the database? In plain text? Please give us the URL so that we can avoid it.

Comment: @Jonasw just give me hint if you aware with it.

Comment: Post your actual code here rather than a link to a file in the cloud

Comment: @RamRaider code is to long so i can't put here

Comment: Plaintext? It's crazy! Read [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and remember it – never store passwords without hashing. Never.

Comment: @Sylogista thank you Sir.

Comment: even you can just echo `******` instead of `$row['password']`

Comment: @AhmedGinani thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: IMHO, the question falls under these 3 categories: 1) Unclear 2) Too broad 3) Why not working. We shouldn't have to fetch your code from an external source. You should have posted a minimal example of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual practice would be to store an encrypted password into your database, and when a user logs in, you encrypt the entered password and test the result against the encrypted password stored in the database.

Further reading on php encryption can be found here:
[Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)